# Take down a WebPage from a iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm currently developping an overlay by using a google chrome extension.
Let me explain the architecture. I have my Extension which call in his content_script : overlay.js. This file will inject my toolbar on the web page by using

```
overlayURL = chrome.extension.getURL("overlay.html"),
iframe = $('<iframe id="YouroverlayFrame" src="'+overlayURL+'">');

body.append(iframe);
```

So the goal is that overlay.html will appear at the top of my windows. But i have a little problem, it's that my iframe, hide the real web page i'm visiting. So i wanted to know how it can be possible to take down all the web page for something like : 40px and then the overlay won't override the web page.

Example to be easier :

With the overlay: http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/2329/withy.png

Without the overlay: http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/1708/without.png

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : 24/02/2011 - 18:49

I've already tried this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('body').setAttribute("style", "margin-bottom: 40px;");
</script>
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to inject HTML into the page (like an iframe), you should be able to add margin to the top of the `<body>` tag in the amount of the height of your iframe. That ***should*** fix it for ***most*** sites.

In JavaScript it'd be:

```
document.body.style.marginTop = '30px'; // or whatever your height is
```

Let me know if this works out for you.

Comment: That's what i've tried but it didn't work.

<script type="text/javascript">    document.getElementById('body').setAttribute("style", "margin-bottom: 40px;");
</script>

Comment: I was wondering if this also takes down `position: absolute` elements. Will they stay or will they be moved down?

Comment: See the code I added. `'body'` isn't an ID. So you need to get the first element of the elements on the page which are `body` elements. Also `bottom-margin` doesn't exist and is on the wrong end of the element. Your could would be changed to: `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].setAttribute('style', 'margin-top: 40px;');` it should be noted that this will blow away any other styles that are on the 'style' attribute of the body tag.

Comment: @pimvdb most times `position:absolute;` elements are positioned relative to the 'body' container. Since margin is *outside* that, it should just push them down.

Comment: @sholsinger it didnt work. Your code make a margin-top for the iframe, i need a margin top for the web page.

Comment: You cannot do this from within the iframe, your javascript would have be to appended to the document that contains the iframe.

Comment: I've put your code on the js who "host" the iframe and it work. Thanks a lot !